# Is "lest" always followed by "should"?

Tags: conjunctions, should

I remember my grandfather giving examples of "lest" like

> ...lest you **should** fail.

Is "lest" always followed by "should" because I see "lest" all the times without being followed by "should" in some articles and novels, but I am not sure if they are grammatically correct.

Please provide examples of such exceptions.

Comment: **Not necessarily.** *"he spent whole days in his room, wearing headphones lest he disturb anyone"* example from ODO

Comment: You can search for definitions and examples on Google. Search "define" followed by a word. In this case, "define lest"

Comment: "...lest you fail." works.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Disha. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: *Lest* is a largely archaic word which is best used rarely and with an ear tuned to it's idiomatic contexts.

Answer (score 4):

*Lest* is generally followed by a verb clause in the [subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive). The word *should* is just a way to put a clause into the future subjunctive. Some examples found online:

- I won’t waste your time responding point-by-point **lest** I give credence to unsubstantiated allegations and tortured innuendo.
- Now, **lest** I appear ungrateful for the relative privilege I
  personally enjoy in the world, let me be quick to acknowledge that
  fact here.
- Don’t push people too hard, **lest** you damage close friendships
  unnecessarily.

These examples are not in the subjunctive, and sound wrong to me:

- I suppose it is unwise of me to make this confession now, **lest** our
  insurance company reads this article. (I would say *lest our insurance company **should** read this article*)
- **Lest** people did not get the point, he went on to say they ”are the
  vilest form of human life” and should ”rot in hell”. (I would say *Lest people fail to get the point* or *Lest people miss the point*.)

Comment: +1 Well explained; well found; & I agree with your last two examples.

Comment: Wait, what’s “future subjunctive”?  English has never had such a thing, not even during the Old English period. Latin never had a future subjunctive either.  Only Iberian languages developed this form, and today mostly only Portuguese and Galician retain it in the living language.  Old English had present and past tenses with indicative and subjunctive moods possible. To put in today's language, the verb *be* can be said to have the past subjunctive inflection of *were* and the present subjunctive inflection of *be*. But there never was a future subjunctive and there isn’t one now.